# udhcpc starting before PHY is up

Tags: linux, networking, udhcpc

I'm having a issue with my Ethernet PHY not being up before eth0 tries to get an IP address

This is my etc/network/interfaces

```
# Configure Loopback
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
post-up /etc/network/if-post-up.d/nfs
```

And this is the log

```
Starting network...
eth0: device MAC address 7e:f1:78:29:23:d0
stmmac_open: failed PTP initialisation
udhcpc (v1.22.1) started
Sending discover...
Sending discover...
Sending discover...
No lease, failing
libphy: stmmac-0:01 - Link is Up - 100/Full
```

As you can see only after udhcpc stops trying to get an IP address is the PHY fully started.

Is there a way to make udhcpc wait for the PHY to be started?
Thanks